# Woocommerce check out won't stop spinning

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have finally come to the last stage of developing this store and would like to have it up and running today. However, after I installed stripe payment gateway and did the final test by purchasing the goods with PDF file attachement ready to download, it appeared that the checkout page won't stop spinning and did not take me anywhere. When I inspected element to see the error it showed up like in the picture below.

[image]

***"Failed to load resource : the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"***

You can see the store at http://www.pata.org/shop

I did examine at System status of woo commerce and found that my PHP limit is too low so I set it up to 96MB. Still it has the same problem. I am using shared hosting plan with bluest right now. I am not sure if that cause the problem.

I disable AJAX but Stripe payment gateway did not let me process the payment.

Has anybody ever experienced this? How to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a default theme and all your other plugins disabled? (so, just WooCommerce and Stripe)